# Winforms Arabic Input text box

Tags: c#, .net

on my windows application form (c#) , i have arabic and english text boxes. for Arabic text boxes i want to automatically shift my language to arabic without presshing (alt + shift). I found this solution on internet and i implemented it on TextBox Enter

```
 private void TextArabs_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {              
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo TypeOfLanguage = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar");
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage);   

        }
```

But still when i type in text box it types english letters instead of arabic. what should i do

Comment: Try `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = TypeOfLanguage;`

Comment: I think.you want the got focus event

Comment: i tried System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture  , but still no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this way :

```
private void TextArabs_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {              
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage =
                InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages[1];   

        }
```

0: Language 1 that installed on your system
1: Language 2 that installed on your system ,...

Updated :

```
 InputLanguage arabic;
        InputLanguage english;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            arabic = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
            english = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
            int count = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages[i].LayoutName.Contains("Arabic"))
                {
                    arabic = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages[i];
                }
                if (InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages[i].LayoutName.Contains("English"))
                {
                    english = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages[i];
                }
            }
        }
        private void txtArabic_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = arabic;
        }

        private void txtEnglish_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = english;
        }
```

Comment: If user have installed multiple language then what will be the proper way? or how we can know that 0 is arabic or english?

Comment: @Tanveer this link can be helpful http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsarabic/archive/2007/04/29/changing-the-input-language-in-a-textbox-at-runtime.aspx