# EditText inputType & Number Format in Arabic Culture

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

We have an app which is working in English(U.S) Culture and now we are trying to support Arabic Locale.

1. We are using the Edittext inputType  as numberDecimal in application . But it opens the keyboard with English Numbers instead of arabic numbers keyboard. How to configure it programatically in code behind?

   **Note:** While setting the Edittext inputType  as "textMultiLine" ,it opens the Arabic keyboard as default. But while setting numberDecimal for EditText it opens with US Culture number keyboard.
2. How to change the number format separator dot('.') to comma(',') for arabic Locale  with Keyboard while typing in Edit Text?

Note: We have a device with Arabic Locale supported.

Comment: Maybe you can check this
[Winforms Arabic Input text box][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248300/winforms-arabic-input-text-box

Comment: Thanks , but we are trying to achieve this for Android.

Comment: @Kathir Any success?

Answer (score 0):

1)You can't.  The keyboard is a separate app, and it alone decides what to display.  If it doesn't have support for arabic numbers, then it won't display them.  I don't know if any of the major keyboards actually support that, none did 2 years ago when I worked at one and was up on their feature sets.

2)You an get what the system knows about the locale from DecimalFormatSymbols  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html   If the phone does not have the arabic locale installed, it may not have the correct values.  In that case you'd have to live with it or roll your own formatting on all numbers.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. Kindly find the updated question block for response with Notes.                                                                                                                Kindly clarify if we set EditText InputType property to NumberDecimal , Android will always open with en_US Number Keypad ?

Comment: Android will tell the keyboard to open and tell it the edit field is numeric.  The keyboard, which is itself an app and not part of android, will decide what to display in response to that.  Its completely possible for a keyboard to support arabic numbers in that case-  I just don't know of any that do.  Its not about using an en-US number pad, its about them deciding its not worth the time/energy to make any other type.

Answer (score 0):

To have Arabic numbers and also Arabic font, try using TypeFace.
first copy a Arabic .TTF Font which includes Arabic numbers to your **"assets/fonts"**.

Then in your activity set Arabic Typeface

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FONT.TTF");
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    et.setTypeface(tf);
    }
```

For decimal separator

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

     Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FONT.TTF");
     EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
     et.setTypeface(tf);
     et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    double dbl = 0;
                    String txt;
                    if (s != null) {
                        try {
                            dbl = Double.parseDouble(s.toString().replace(',', '.'));
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            //Error
                        }
                        txt = String.valueOf(dbl);
                        et.setText(txt, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

and also add

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:digits="0123456789.,"
```

to your EditText layout

Comment: Thanks Milad. But we are already displaying the arabic texts by placing the Arabic contents in Resources Folder. We need to know the feasibilities on Edittext inputType as numberDecimal for Arabic Input method with Keyboards?

Comment: You mean you need to have Arabic numbers in EditText Field or on keyboard?

Comment: On Keyboard while focussing in EditText for entering Arabic Numbers.