# C# textbox with mixed Western and Arabic text

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding, arabic

I would like to display mixed western & arabic data read from a file into a text box.

An example of the data is I want to display is:

```
"You have", "يوجد لديك"
```

I read the data in as follows:

```
String tsIn = File.ReadAllText(tbxTSFileName.Text, Encoding.UTF8);
tbxBefore.Text = tsIn;
```

I cannot see any properties that let me set the textbox to "mixed" encoding.

When I open the file in Notepad++ I select Encoding>Character sets>Arabic>ISO 8859-6.

To make matters even more complicated, I would want to use the same textbox for other languages too, so the solution needs to work in all/most cases.

Comment: Windows uses Unicode natively. There is no mixed encoding. Text editors have such settings because there's still a lot of text content out there in legacy character encodings.

Comment: ISO 8859-6 is not UTF8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Winforms Arabic Input text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248300/winforms-arabic-input-text-box)

Answer (score 0):

You need to show us the assignment to the textbox - for instance, is this a WinForms textbox, a WPF textbox or an HTML textbox.

Strings in C# are unicode - so can definitely hold Arabic.

You are reading UTF8 format which supports Arabic so I cannot tell what your actual problem is. Your tsIn could easily contain Arabic - is your problem that you cannot see Arabic in your WinForms TextBox ? This link has a lot of detail on displaying arabic on WinForms 
[Winforms Arabic Input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248300/winforms-arabic-input-text-box)

Comment: It's a WinForms textbox. The only things I have changed from the default properties are to set it to multi-line. I've updated the question to show how the textbox is being set.

Comment: This is then a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248300/winforms-arabic-input-text-box which shows how to get WinForms to display Arabic text.